# How to get context of the object that calls a method? 'This' doesn't work. JS

Tags: javascript, parameters, chain

How can I get the reference to what's being return to the method call? Like how we have the arguments variable to get all arguments being passed to a function. How can I get what's being returned to so I can chain a function?

```
let myFunc = function(obj, num){
  if (typeof obj === 'number' && typeof num === 'undefined') {
    num = obj;
    obj = this;
  }
  console.log(obj.name);
  console.log(num);
  console.log(Object(this));
  return obj;
};

let myObj = {
  name: 'Devin',
};

myFunc(myObj, 1);

myObj.myFunc = myFunc;

myObj.myFunc(2).myFunc(3);
```

**edit:** It's written out this because it's currently used in many places that I will have to refactor down the road but do not have time to right now. So I'm trying to do a few changes that don't affect current code but will work the way I want moving forward. myFunc(myObj, 1) is current but I have done a minor refactor to inline like so... myObj.myFunc(myObj, 2).myFunc(myObj, 3) ... but I thought I could remove myObj as an argument since it's being returned.

**edit 2:** Changed arrow es6 function to using function keyword to keep this context and added console.log(Object(this)). But still getting undefined from myObj.name and Object(this) only gives the argument

**ANSWER:** The problem was that I was using an arrow function and that I had typeof num === 'number' instead of equal to 'undefined'. Thank you.

Comment: The `myFunc` has **two** parameters. What do you expect then when you call it with just one argument? The other will be `undefined` and thus your `if` will never be executed.

Comment: It's unclear what `myFunc` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

`myFunc.bind(myObj)` doesn't serve any good purpose because arrows cannot be bound. In order to use dynamic `this` it should be regular function, e.g. shorthand syntax:

```
let myObj = {
  name: 'Devin',
  myFunc(num) {
    console.log(num);
    return this;
  }
};

myObj.myFunc(2).myFunc(3); // basically a noop
```